# NativeWind styles not being applied

Tags: react-native, babeljs, tailwind-css

I am seeing not styling changes despite installing NativeWind CSS.

I have followed the trouble shooting guide but this has not helped (https://www.nativewind.dev/guides/troubleshooting)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "betting-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~47.0.9",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    plugins: ["nativewind/babel"],
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
  };
};
```

tailwind.config.js

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./screens/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  // ...
};
```

Comment: add some examples of nativewind styling usage in your App